# recommended battery for 750 watt ups

Tags: battery, ups, requirements

I have a ups with capacity 750 Watt, please advise if i can use 175 Amp battery with 750 watt ups? otherwise please advise suitable battery capacity for 750 watt ups so it can perform good.

Comment: Note that battery capacity is usually given in terms of voltage and one of (sometimes both of) amp-hours and watt-hours. Ampere is a flow rate, amp-hours is a capacity.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a battery that is recommended for your UPS by the manufacturer, or is a direct replacement for the existing battery with equivalent rating. Use of alternative batteries can cause issues with the charging or reporting circuitry of the UPS, and can even potentially be a fire or explosive hazard.

Since you did not state the specific model and rating of the UPS or existing battery(s), this is the best answer I can provide.